# Error: host 'testphp.vulnweb.com' does not exist on sqlmap kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I am running kali linux in virtualbox under ubuntu 14.04 lts. I am getting following error while executing `root@kali:~# sqlmap -u http://testphp.vulnweb.com/listproducts.php?cat=1 --dbs` in sqlmap.
please help.

```
root@kali:~# sqlmap -u http://testphp.vulnweb.com/listproducts.php?cat=1 --dbs
         _
 ___ ___| |_____ ___ ___  {1.0-dev-nongit-20150914}
|_ -| . | |     | .'| . |
|___|_  |_|_|_|_|__,|  _|
      |_|           |_|   http://sqlmap.org

[!] legal disclaimer: Usage of sqlmap for attacking targets without prior mutual consent is illegal. It is the end user's responsibility to obey all applicable local, state and federal laws. Developers assume no liability and are not responsible for any misuse or damage caused by this program

[*] starting at 23:19:09

[23:19:11] [WARNING] using '/root/.sqlmap/output' as the output directory
[23:19:11] [CRITICAL] host 'testphp.vulnweb.com' does not exist

[*] shutting down at 23:19:11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change `false` to `true`

And then

```
service network-manager restart
```

as described in [Can't access internet in kali virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/678893/cant-access-internet-in-kali-virtualbox)